# Beautiful Soup: findall and quoted classes

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

I am a new python user banging my head against a wall on a BS issue.  My target page contains the snipits below:

```
<div class=rbHeader>
<span role="heading" aria-level="3" class="ws_bold">
Experience Level</span>
</div>

<div class="  row  result" id="p_bc0437dce636c6f4" data-jk="bc0437dce636c6f4" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting" data-tn-component="organicJob">

...

</div>
```

I have parsed the page as follows:

```
   target = Soup(urllib.urlopen(url), "lxml")
```

If I run

```
targetElements = target.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'rbheader'})
print targetElements
```

I get

```
 [<div class="rbHeader">\n<span aria-level="3" class="ws_bold" role="heading">\nExperience Level</span>\n</div>]
```

but if I run

```
targetElements = target.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'  row  result'})
print targetElements
```

i get

```
[]
```

This is the case no matter which class i try to select if that class is in quotes.  i can only seem to find classes that are outside of quotes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best
Ryan

Comment: There is no difference between quotes or no quotes. These are all identical **in meaning**, even if expressed using different *syntax*: `class=foo`, `class="foo"`, `class='foo'`. The difference is that `row result` means something specific (a *list* of multiple classes) which bs4 is looking for.

Comment: can you send me the source url of the page which you are trying to  get output?

Comment: just using targetElements = target.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'result'}) seems to work and since it result is not used anywhere else, i get what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are stripped from all classes, always.

You can just get one class:

```
targetElements = target.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'row'})
```

...or:

```
targetElements = target.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'result'})
```

If you are suspicious that each of these may return too many results, you can do:

```
soup.select('div.row.result')
```

....where `soup` is your instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on your `div`:

```
div_test='<div class=rbHeader><span role="heading" aria-level="3" class="ws_bold">Experience Level</span></div><div class="  row  result" id="p_bc0437dce636c6f4" data-jk="bc0437dce636c6f4" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting" data-tn-component="organicJob"></div>'
target = bs4.BeautifulSoup(div_test,'html.parser')
```

1, class name is case sensitive, your code

```
targetElements = target.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'rbheader'})
print targetElements
```

will get nothing `[]`.

```
targetElements = target.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'rbHeader'})
print targetElements
```

Will give you:

```
[<div class="rbHeader"><span aria-level="3" class="ws_bold" role="heading">Experience Level</span></div>]
```

2, For the code:

```
targetElements = target.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'  row  result'})
print targetElements
```

It will give you the result instead of nothing:

```
[<div class=" row result" data-jk="bc0437dce636c6f4" data-tn-component="organicJob" id="p_bc0437dce636c6f4" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting"></div>]
```